# Custom Grafana alert viewer/dashboard

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable, grafana-alerts

Using Grafana 9.4. Does Grafana expose environment variables of alerts, for me to create my own dashboard and views? Grafana has the alert rule config UI, but that's not what I want to use as an alert dashboard. The only thing I see is the Alert List panel, which is limiting. I need to get hold of some variable say active_alerts, and be able to slice and dice it however I want using alert labels.

Comment: What do you mean by "environment variables of alerts"? Are looking for something similar to [`ALERTS`](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=ALERTS) metric in Prometheus?

Comment: Yes indeed. I’m hoping Grafana exposes an alter type instance that I can use to report or display active alert properties my way.

Comment: AFAIK,  there is no built-in way to do it. But maybe you can combine json data source plugin and alerting api to imitate something like this.